# Google Sheets - insert row increments formula cell

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I've created a results page for a board game we play. We enter the results on the Last Game sheet. I then click Save Results which inserts rows and copies the result data accordingly into three sheets, Game Totals, Player 1 and Player 2.

The Last Game sheet has number of wins, averages and such which all use formulas, e.g.

=COUNTIF('Game Totals'!D2:D164, "SUSAN")

D1 is a header row. The latest results are copied into the inserted row, D2.

My problem is while I want D164 to increment to D165 in the formula above I want D2 to remain as D2, but it increments to D3.

I read up a little on using $D$2 but that doesn't stop it from incrementing to D3.

Any help most gratefully appreciated
Cheers
Johnny.

Comment: Can you share your sheet?

Comment: More than happy to share. I'm new to this forum, and hence haven't posted before, so will figure out how to share the sheet(s). Stand by. ;-) And thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that cell `'Game Totals'!D1` does not equal `Susan` and does not move when you insert rows, you can start the range reference from that cell:

`=countif('Game Totals'!D1:D164, "SUSAN")`

Comment: Thanks for this. As D1 is the header row it'll never equal Susan, and the script that Inserts the row skips over the header intentionally so the new row is always D2.

Comment: This does cover a few of the 'stats' I'm collecting, and I only gave one example. I still have to figure out how to stop - =AVERAGE(Susan!$L$2:L164) from incrementing L2 automatically while incrementing L164.

Comment: The `average()` function ignores cells that do not contain numbers, so you can simply use `=average(Susan!L1:L)`.